# Issue formatting ASCII file

Tags: qgis, ascii, formatting

I am trying to open an ASCII file in QGIS but I am having some difficulties with the formatting.

I know the X and Y field names must be selected, but under 'sample data', the data appears under one column, rather than individual columns, so I can't set the appropriate X and Y fields.

Attached is a screenshot of the issue.

I am uploading the file via Layer -> Add layer -> Add delimited text layer.

[image]

Comment: Your screen capture is missing the important information about what character you have configured to mean a field separator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Check `Space` as delimiter
2. Uncheck `First record has field names`.
3. Select X and Y field.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!